# How to save Eclipse task tags and bookmarks

Tags: eclipse

I am rephrasing the question. How do I backup Tasks and Bookmarks, which are saved in the workspace? I've been using Java task tags, but they do allow marking them as complete. I've started converting to a combinations of Mylyn taks and Java task tags, but it I would rather just Tasks, if only I could save them. Are there plans for unifying the concepts of Task, Bookmark, and Java task tags?

Comment: I guess you just missed to enable searching for task tags (which is disabled by default): _Project > Properties: Task Tags_. With that, you do not export/import them since the task tags are in your code.

Comment: That option is the same as preferences -> compiler -> task tags and that is used to generate Java tasks which are different than Tasks (different than Mylyn tasks). The later can be marked as complete but are stored in the workspace unlike Java tasks stored in the source. I need a way to save/backup Tasks.

Comment: I see. I was not aware of tasks not created and deleted by the task scanner.

Answer (score 0):

This might be "Task List and Contexts".  You get to this from "Export".  If you've already tried this, then I don't know what the answer is.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it is for the Mylin task list rather than task tags and bookmarks.

Comment: Ok. Update your post to make that distinction clear, and I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The feature to **export and import tasks does not yet exist** and there are no plans to implement this enhancement in the near future:

[Eclipse bug 42320 - [Markers] export the tasks to a file](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=42320)

Be the one who implements it. It would be nice to have import/export for tasks.